# Angular fileupload dropzone does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I have the following controller:.

```
    app.controller('DashboardController', ['$http', '$scope','$sessionStorage','$log','Session','api','FileUploader',  function ($http, $scope, $sessionStorage,$log, Session, api,FileUploader) {

    $scope.post = {user_id: $sessionStorage.user.user.id};


    var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'js/controllers/upload.php'
    });

    // FILTERS

    uploader.filters.push({
        name: 'customFilter',
        fn: function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, options) {
            return this.queue.length < 10;
        }
    });

    // CALLBACKS

    uploader.onWhenAddingFileFailed = function(item /*{File|FileLikeObject}*/, filter, options) {
        console.info('onWhenAddingFileFailed', item, filter, options);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(fileItem) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingFile', fileItem);
    };
    uploader.onAfterAddingAll = function(addedFileItems) {
        console.info('onAfterAddingAll', addedFileItems);
    };
    uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function(item) {
        item.file.test = "gg";
        console.info('onBeforeUploadItem', item);
    };
    uploader.onProgressItem = function(fileItem, progress) {
        console.info('onProgressItem', fileItem, progress);
    };
    uploader.onProgressAll = function(progress) {
        console.info('onProgressAll', progress);
    };
    uploader.onSuccessItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onSuccessItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onErrorItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onErrorItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCancelItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCancelItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteItem = function(fileItem, response, status, headers) {
        console.info('onCompleteItem', fileItem, response, status, headers);
    };
    uploader.onCompleteAll = function() {
        console.info('onCompleteAll');
    };

    console.info('uploader', uploader);
}]);
```

With the following html:

```
<div class="b-a b-2x b-dashed wrapper-lg bg-white text-center m-b" nv-file-over="" over-class="b-info" uploader="uploader">
                               Base drop zone
```

my goal is to upload as soon as i drop an item on the `Base drop zone`

However whenever i attempt to pull something into it does not take the item. Can anyone see what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply include `nv-file-drop=""` on your div.

`<div class="b-a b-2x b-dashed wrapper-lg bg-white text-center m-b" nv-file-drop="" nv-file-over="" over-class="b-info" uploader="uploader">Base drop zone</div>`

Try to drop a file on it, and check your browser's console for the events that are getting called.
You can then invoke `uploader.uploadAll()` on `onAfterAddingFile` event for example.